# P5: How to create a semisolid platform

Tags: javascript, p5.js, p5.play

I am building a physics/movement test in p5.js, to compare a few options I have. Does anyone know how to make a semi-solid platform? The concept is just a one-way platform, pretty much. I can't find a documentation on https://p5play.org, or on a simple google search.

The only attempt I have made was to check if the player is touching the bottom, and then increase velocity, but this could be too easily exploited, and I couldnt find a way to check if its touching the bottom without adding another sprite entirely.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What's a semi-solid platform? Have you made any attempt at implementing it?

Comment: I edited the post to clarify and add my first attempt/idea. Any thoughts?